# On elements of $L^{1} [0,1]$ space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

As we know the elements of $L^{p}$ spaces are classes of function not merely functions. Having this in mind, let $[f] \in L^{1} [0,1]$ for some function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$.  Assume we know that the class $[f]$ admits a continuous representative, that is there exists a continuous $g$ with $g(x) = f(x)$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$. Clearly there is only one $g$ with this property.

Now my question is that is there a way to identify $g$ purely in terms of $f$? For example is there any operator (formula) that receives $f$ as an input and gives us $g$ the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xg(t)\,dt=g(x)$?

Comment: first equality doesn't hold for all $x \in [0,1]$, does it?

Comment: @Redshoes I'm awfully rusty on this, but it should hold, since $f(t)=g(t)$ for almost all $t\in[0,x]$.

Comment: Sounds right. I had feeling that $\int_{0}^{x}  f(t) \; dt$ is just absolutely continuous function which may not be differentiable. I forgot $f$ is something more that being in $L^1$.